# Include Caller_id if all corresponding rows doesn't match certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `CallTable` with columns name `caller_id` and `Is_picked_up` which contain the status whether is picked up or not.

```
Caller_id     Is_picked
1                no  
1                yes 
1                no
2                no  
3                no
```

I want the callers who never picked up the calls. in above case 2 and 3 would be the ouput.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `group by` each unique `Caller_id` and check if conditional count for `Is_picked`'s column value *yes* is 0 within group:

```
select `Caller_id`
from `CallTable`
group by `Caller_id`
having sum(`Is_picked` = 'yes') = 0
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32f0d/1)**

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia: Thank you for putting a fiddle together

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT caller_id
FROM   call_table a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   call_table b
                   WHERE  a.caller_id = b.called_id AND is_picked = 'yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery to fetch all records having at least one "yes" in `is_picked` column and using `NOT IN` condition.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CALLER_ID FROM CallTable C1 where C1.CALLER_ID not in
(SELECT distinct CALLER_ID C2 FROM CallTable C2 having count(is_picked = "yes") > 1 );
```

SQLFiddle Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea507/13